# need help to find a way to get something form the head with xpath()

Tags: scrapy

i know how to get the response.xpath('//head/script').getall()

the problem is i have to get a speciel script form the list and cant find out how to do it. the list is random so cant just say list_foo[foo1] because it swapping its place the http head look like this

```
    head
    link rel="canonical" href=" /
    meta name="robots" content="noarchive" /
    script data-script="TagManagerDataLayer" .... /script
    script data-script="TagManagerScript" .... /script
    script ... /script
    script var item={} /script
    script ... /script
    /head
```

i need to scrape the "var item={}"

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
//script[contains(., "var item={}")]

Comment: i will try it because that would be so much better if not i found another way with a re call but thx help atleast :)